# com.google.gdata - Maven Dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I am new to maven. My maven project has the following dependencies -

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
            <artifactId>gdata-analytics</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
            <artifactId>gdata-analytics-meta</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
            <artifactId>gdata-client</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
            <artifactId>gdata-client-meta</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
            <artifactId>gdata-core-cpha</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.collect</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-collect</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

When I run the mvn clean install command, I get the following error -

```
 Failed to execute goal on project cpha-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project cpha-common:cpha-service:jar:3.4.5: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.google.gdata:gdata-client:jar:1.0 (present, but unavailable), com.google.gdata:gdata-client-meta:jar:1.0 (present, but unavailable), com.google.gdata:gdata-core-cpha:jar:1.0 (present, but unavailable), com.google.collect:google-collect:jar:1.0-rc1 (present, but unavailable): Could not find artifact com.google.gdata:gdata-client:jar:1.0 in repo2 (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
```

When I look at the configured repository within the parent maven pom.xml, I see the following but traversing the link - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gdata yields no such package. How do I resolve this? No repositories seem to have the com.google.gdata package.

```
<repository>
            <id>repo2</id>
            <name>repo2</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
```

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score -1):

The error message you've posted is related to cpha-common:cpha-service artifact and not to com.google.gdata artifact. The latter are available in offical maven repo. So I assume it is related to your parent project.